# Django REST Framework: serializing an ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having huge issues with Django REST Framework and its serializers in relation to a model with an ImageField

Here's the code for my model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_image_filename_and_path,
                                   width_field="image_width",
                                   height_field="image_height",
                                   null=False,
                                   blank=False)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
```

and here's the serializer:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('image_file',)
        read_only = ('id', 'image_width', 'image_height')
```

id, image_width and image_height are set as read_only fields, as I want them to be generated by the model class. ID is something I couldn't even provide when first creating a model instance.

I've had much trouble. In the current state, I have a test that looks like this:

```
class PhotoSerializerTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_native_data_type_serialization(self):
        img_file = create_generic_image_file('test_img.jpg',
                                             'image/jpeg')

        p = Photo(image_file=img_file)
        p.save()

        serialization = PhotoSerializer(p)

        expected_id = p.id
        expected_image_width = p.image_width
        expected_image_height = p.image_height

        print(serialization)
        actual_id = serialization.data['id']
        actual_image_width = serialization.data['image_width']
        actual_image_height = serialization.data['image_height']

        self.assertEqual(expected_id, actual_id)
        self.assertEqual(expected_image_width, actual_image_width)
        self.assertEqual(expected_image_height, actual_image_height)
```

Here's the function that I call to create the generic image file for the test:

```
def create_generic_image_file(name, content_type):

    path = '\\test_files\\test_image_generic.jpg'
    file_path = BASE_DIR + path
    file_name = name
    content = open(file_path, 'rb').read()

    image_file = SimpleUploadedFile(name=file_name,
                                    content=content,
                                    content_type=content_type)

    return image_file
```

In present state, I'm left with an error as follows:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
..PhotoSerializer(<Photo: Photo object>):
    image_file = ImageField()
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_native_data_type_serialization (photo_broker.test_serializers.PhotoSerializerTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<local_path>\test_serializers.py", line 25, in test_native_data_type_serialization
    actual_id = serialization.data['id']
KeyError: 'id'
```

I can't even recall all the different errors that I've gotten previously, but I'm sure they'll pop up when this one's cleared.

edit:

Ok, I cleared the key error by moving all the fields back to PhotoSerializer.Meta.fields instead of PhotoSerializer.Meta.read_only. Now I'm back to one of my original questions. Let me explain with a test:

```
def test_create_model_from_serializer(self):
    img_file = create_generic_image_file('test_img.jpg',
                                         'image/jpeg')

    data = {'image_file': img_file,
            'id': 7357,
            'image_width': 1337,
            'image_height': 715517}

    s = PhotoSerializer(data=data)
    print(type(s))
    print(s.is_valid())
    print(s)
```

This yields clearly likable output and the serializer validates without a cough, but this is not what I want to be able to do. The ID and the dimensions should be calculated by the model. Not to whatever values by the serializer.

If I remove them from the fields attribute, then I can never get them into my serialization either. That's where I need them.

Or am I getting confused here and there actually is a valid use case, where I originally create the model normally, without going through the serializer?

Comment: If you're looking to calculate a field, you want this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Correct, it should be done using `SerializerMethodField`. Also width and height are already there for the `ImageField`. Use them instead.